How to save environment variables with newlines into .env file?
I'm probably missing something here but I'm trying to save environment variables with newlines into a .env file. Ideally I want to do this with all available env variables (output of env).
Take this variable:
export MY_VAR="Line 1
Line 2
Line 3"

How do I save this in a .env file that would look like:
variables.env
MY_VAR=Line 1\nLine2\nLine3

And how can I do this with all available env variables, like from env? I tried this:
while IFS= read -r -d '' line; do
    line=$(echo -n "$line" | sed '$!s/$/\\n/' | tr -d '\n')
    echo "$line" >> variables.env
done < <(env -0)

But this also doesn't work for \r.

What is the format of this final .env file? Do you just want newlines encoded as \n? Do you want full C-style strings (covering also \t, \r, etc)? Is this a format that is documented somewhere?  There are lots of ways to encode text that preserve newline and other special characters; it will be helpful to know what you want in more detail.

I think you should, for clarification, provide a table, showing which characters in the variable you want to map into which printable representation. Obviously you want to convert a hex 0A into \n, and perhaps a hex 0D into \r. but how would you, for instance convert a hex 0B?

My goal is to have it slurped up with golang viper's ReadInConfig(), so the env file itself can't have multiple lines as that breaks the .env file rules. Ideally it's all C-style strings as you said jwd, but newlines is definitely going to break the file

From a comment on my answer from @jepner, apparently there's an NPM standard-ish package for using .env files. I don't know whether you had that in mind or if you're using the name .env more generally, but you might take a look at it. https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv

This might be good enough for whatever it is you're trying to do:
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

export MY_VAR="Line 1
Line 2
Line 3"

export MY_VAR2=17

regexp="^[$]?'(.*)'$"
while IFS= read -r -d '' line; do
    printf -v line '%q' "$line"
    # or you could do this if your bash version is 4.4 or newer:
    #    line="${line@Q}"
    if [[ "$line" =~ $regexp ]]; then
        line="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
    fi
    printf '%s\n' "$line"
done < <(env -0)


$ ./tst.sh | grep MY_VAR
MY_VAR=Line 1\nLine 2\nLine 3
MY_VAR2=17


This returns line 11: ${line@Q}: bad substitution in a bash terminal

Get a new version of bash as yours is very out of date (that feature was introduced nearly 10 years ago in bash 4.4, we're currently on bash 5.2) but I added an alternative way of doing essentially the same thing.

Great call - didn't know my vscode bash was that outdated. Updating fixed it, but also thank you for the backwards compatible version.

This is difficult to do with env. The default output of env is fundamentally ambiguous in the presence of newlines. After export FOO=$'zero\nBAR=one', env will print two lines, FOO=zero and BAR=one, impossible to distinguish from two variables $FOO and $BAR.
$ export FOO=$'zero\nBAR=one' ; export BAR=one ; env | grep -e FOO -e BAR
FOO=zero
BAR=one
BAR=one
$ 

If you happen to be using the GNU coreutils version of the env command, it has a -0 or --null option that ends each output line with a null character rather than a newline. This is unambiguous, since environment variable names and values cannot contain null characters (a null character terminates a string).
env -0 > .env

If your env command doesn't have this option, you can write a program (perhaps in C or Perl) that does the same thing.
You asked about saving the environment to a .env file. You didn't ask about reading it afterwards. You can probably use bash's read -r -d $'\0' to read lines from the file. (I haven't quite gotten this to work myself. You'll probably have to play games with $IFS to avoid word-splitting.)

.env files don't have the same semantics as shell, so reading one from shell isn't much different from reading one from any other language: you need to write a proper parser.

@chepner Is there some standard format for .env files? If so, I wasn't aware of it. Can you provide a reference?

As far as I know, there is just the de facto standard set by how the original(?) JavaScript library functions.

@chepner Hmm. I had never heard of that, and I wouldn't assume that that's what the OP has in mind. .env seems like a reasonable name for a file that stores the environment, not necessarily in any standard format. I'll post a comment on the question.

Once you saved the env in a file (as @Keith Thompson) showed, you can execute a program with that environment with something like this
#! /usr/bin/env python3

import subprocess
with open(".env") as file:
    env = dict(filter(lambda e:len(e)==2, map(lambda kv:tuple(kv.split("=")), map(bytes.decode, file.read().encode().split(b"\x00")))))
subprocess.run(["mycommand"], env=env)


This is splitting on the NUL bytes and construct the dict of (key,value) pairs.
